# how to read inputs entered from command prompt in my perl script

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl and looking for a way to read inputs entered from command prompt ( not passed as command line arguments ). 
for eg:-
when I run my script say,
**perl test.pl**

I would like to display a string say, **enter the number :** and wait for the user to enter the value and read that value into a parameter in my perl script and then further go on with the next input.

Comment: You need to show some effort.  I did a google search with the search terms "read keyboard input perl" and found an answer at the first link I clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Enter your input:\n";
my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;
print "You typed: $input\n";
```

this will get user input from cmd

Comment: No problem. Accept the answer if you problem solved. Will help others as well.